# How to convert a JSON attribute which returns a string of numbers to Date

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble to convert an attribute from a JSON which returns a data of type DATE but in this format:
12785950000494 
How to pass this value to the next format YYYY-MM-DD
I hope you can help me 
Thanks!!!

Comment: poss dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-microsoft-json-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

This method will reconstruct your dateTime string:

```
var jsonData = new Date();
var formattedDate =  new Date(jsonData);
var strDate = [formattedDate.getFullYear(), formattedDate.getMonth()+1, formattedDate.getDate()].join("-");
alert(strDate);
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: @tadeogutierrez if you helped pls, check mark for my solution or check as fixed. Thanx ;)

Answer (score 0):

The format for the date is unix timestamp you can use Date API to transform the date.

Read the documentation about date.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
var timestamp = 12785950000494 
var date = new Date(timestamp)
alert(date);
```